# Split sql parameter on comma

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

Below code works for 'Main Stream' or 'Premium' as parameter, however I am trying to make it work for both of them as you can see below, but it doesn't return any results. How can I make the below code work?

```
declare @myParameter varchar(50)
SET @myParameter = 'Main Stream , Premium'


select * FROM sales  
where myCategory IN (@myParameter)
```

Comment: For a detailed discussion on this issue and alternative solutions check out Erland Sommerskogs link on [Arrays in SQL Server 2005](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#CSV)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like

```
--Split
DECLARE @textXML XML
DECLARE @data NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @delimiter NVARCHAR(5)
        
SELECT  @data = 'Main Stream , Premium',
        @delimiter = ','
        
SELECT    @textXML = CAST('<d>' + REPLACE(@data, @delimiter, '</d><d>') + '</d>' AS XML)
SELECT  T.split.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') AS data
FROM    @textXML.nodes('/d') T(split)
```

You could either store this in a temp table, or use it in the IN clause.

For @Hoy comment

You could look at [nodes() Method (xml Data Type)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx)

> The nodes() method is useful when you want to shred an xml data type
> instance into relational data. It allows you to identify nodes that
> will be mapped into a new row.

Also, have a look at [xml Data Type Methods](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx)

You could then use it as

```
select * 
FROM    sales  
where   myCategory IN   (
                            SELECT  T.split.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
                            FROM    @textXML.nodes('/d') T(split)
                        )
```

Comment: Hi, I spent some time trying to understand the code, I couldn't understand how the last 2 rows working, what is (T), what is that syntax ? What should I google to learn that syntax? And finally how to use your code with IN clause

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
select id from dbo.split("24,25,26",',');
```

so you need to to:

```
select * FROM sales  
where myCategory IN ( select id from dbo.split(@myParameter,",");
```

and add split function in your database by running:

```
Create FUNCTION [Split](@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))       
 returns @temptable TABLE (id varchar(8000))       
 as       
  begin       
      declare @idx int       
      declare @slice varchar(8000)       

      select @idx = 1       
          if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

      while @idx!= 0       
      begin       
          set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
          if @idx!=0       
              set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
          else       
              set @slice = @String       

          if(len(@slice)>0)  
              insert into @temptable(id) values(@slice)       

          set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
          if len(@String) = 0 break       
      end   
  return       
  end
  Go
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice solution for a similar issue on [another thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql#2677).
Basically, it uses a function for splitting a string (`@MyParameter` in your case) using a delimiter ('`,`' in your case).

Here is how you call the function:

```
declare @myParameter varchar(50)
SET @myParameter = 'Main Stream,Premium'

--this table will hold delimited values
DECLARE @ParsedTable TABLE 
(   
        [id] [int] NOT NULL,
        [content] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
    --Parsing @myParameter
INSERT INTO @ParsedTable
SELECT * from [dbo].[SplitString](@myParameter, ',')
--SELECT * FROM @ParsedTable --This will show you the values... 
--run the query 
select * FROM sales  
where myCategory IN (SELECT content from @ParsedTable)
```

And here is the code for creating the split functions:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SplitString]') AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT'))
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
go

/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[SplitString]    Script Date: 11/04/2013 19:04:05 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
go

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @StringToDelimit nvarchar(500),
    @deliminator nvarchar(2)
)
RETURNS 
@ReturnTable TABLE 
(
    -- Add the column definitions for the TABLE variable here
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [content] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
        Declare @delimitorIdx int
        Declare @content varchar(50)

        --initialize spaces
        Select @delimitorIdx = charindex(@deliminator,@StringToDelimit,0)
        While @delimitorIdx > 0

        Begin
            Select @content = substring(@StringToDelimit,0,charindex(@deliminator,@StringToDelimit,0))

            Insert Into @ReturnTable(content)
            Select @content

            Select @StringToDelimit = substring(@StringToDelimit,charindex(@deliminator,@StringToDelimit,0)+ 1,len(@StringToDelimit) - charindex(' ',@StringToDelimit,0))

            Select @delimitorIdx = charindex(@deliminator,@StringToDelimit,0)
        end

        If len(@StringToDelimit) > 0
            Insert Into @ReturnTable
            Select @StringToDelimit

    RETURN 
END

go
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @myParameter varchar(50)
SET @myParameter = 'Main Stream , Premium'


select * FROM sales  
where myCategory IN (select * from string_split(@myParameter,','))
```